# Maploader lazy initialization with indexes

Tags: java, distributed, hazelcast

I am having maploader which uses indexes for the for querying

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Customer(String id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

- Maploader

  public class SimpleMapLoader implements MapLoader {
      public Customer load(Integer key) {
          System.out.println("load");
          return null;
      }

  ```
  public Map<Integer, Customer> loadAll(Collection<Integer> keys) {
      System.out.println("loadAll");
      Map<Integer, Customer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Customer>();

      for (Integer k : keys) {
          map.put(k, new Customer(String.valueOf(k), String.valueOf(k)));
      }

      return map;
  }

  public Iterable<Integer> loadAllKeys() {
      System.out.println("loadallkeys");
      List<Integer> map = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          map.add(i);
      }

      return map;
  }
  ```

  }

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Config config = new Config();
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

        final MapConfig customerMapConf = config.getMapConfig("customers");
        final MapStoreConfig customerMapStoreConf = customerMapConf.getMapStoreConfig();
        customerMapStoreConf.setImplementation(new SimpleMapLoader());
        customerMapStoreConf.setEnabled(true);
        customerMapConf.setMapStoreConfig(customerMapStoreConf);
        config.addMapConfig(customerMapConf);
        Map<Integer, String> map = instance.getMap("customers"); 
        instance.shutdown();
    }

}
```

This works absolutely fine map will not be loaded until i touch map for the first time.

But whne i add a index for map .The map is loaded eager irrespective of touching the map.
From Hazelcast documentation
The InitialLoadMode configuration parameter in the class MapStoreConfig has two values: LAZY and EAGER. If InitialLoadMode is set to LAZY, data is not loaded during the map creation. If it is set to EAGER, all the data is loaded while the map is created, and everything becomes ready to use. Also, if you add indices to your map with the MapIndexConfig class or the addIndex method, then InitialLoadMode is overridden and MapStoreConfig behaves as if EAGER mode is on.

But is there any way to override this Eager InitialLoadMode behavior .
I add index the following way

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Config config = new Config();
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

        final MapConfig customerMapConf = config.getMapConfig("customers");
        final MapStoreConfig customerMapStoreConf = customerMapConf.getMapStoreConfig();
        customerMapStoreConf.setImplementation(new SimpleMapLoader());
        customerMapStoreConf.setEnabled(true);
        customerMapConf.setMapStoreConfig(customerMapStoreConf);
        config.addMapConfig(customerMapConf);
        MapIndexConfig indexConfig = new MapIndexConfig();
        indexConfig.setAttribute("name");
        indexConfig.setOrdered(false);
        customerMapConf.setMapIndexConfigs(Arrays.asList(indexConfig));
        customerMapStoreConf.setInitialLoadMode(InitialLoadMode.LAZY);
        Map<Integer, String> map = instance.getMap("customers");

       // System.out.println(map.get("1"));

        instance.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Am using hazelcast 3.7.4.Please suggest if there is a way

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, initial loading mode gets overridden and set to EAGER when you create indexes. You can override productionised behaviour by forking your own branch of Hazelcast code, modify what you want and rebuild it. However, this may adversely impact other areas of the system (e.g. slow loading due to partition threads being occupied for too long), so you will be required to be mindful of risk of being on an unsupported version.

Answer (score 0):

As the doc says

`The InitialLoadMode configuration parameter in the class MapStoreConfig has two values: LAZY and EAGER. If InitialLoadMode is set to LAZY, data is not loaded during the map creation. If it is set to EAGER, all the data is loaded while the map is created, and everything becomes ready to use. Also, if you add indices to your map with the MapIndexConfig class or the addIndex method, then InitialLoadMode is overridden and MapStoreConfig behaves as if EAGER mode is on.`

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html